# Exponential map, Manifold

Tags: manifolds, exponential-function, smooth-manifolds, matrix-exponential, tangent-bundle

For each $x\in M,X\in T_x M$ there exists a maximal interval $I_X\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with $0\in I_X$ and a geodesic $c=c_X$
$$c:I\to M$$
with $c(0)=x,\dot{c}(0)=X$. Let $$C:=\{X\in TM | 1\in I_X\}$$ be a star-shaped
neighborhood of the zero section of $TM$ and define an exponential map
$$\exp:C\to M$$
$$X\mapsto c_X(1).$$ **Now why** if $$X\in C,0\leq t \leq1,$$ then
$$\exp (tX)=c_X(t).$$ Also I do not know where were used the sandwiched
inequalities for $t$,i.e $0\leq t \leq1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c(t)$ is geodesic then $\gamma(t)=c(kt)$ is also a geodesic. Thus given $Y=kX$ with $0<k<1$ we have that $\gamma(t)$ satisfies $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=kc'(0)=kX=Y.$ So, by definition, we have

$$exp_x(kX)=exp_x(Y)=\gamma(1)=c(k).$$

The condition $0\le k\le 1$ is used to guarantee that $Y\in C$ (in other words, to have that $exp_x(Y)$ is defined).

Comment: Do you mean by $\exp_x$ in fact $\exp_X$ ?

Comment: I mean $\exp$ at point $x.$

Comment: But the domain of $\exp$ are vectors $X$ from $TM$ as given by $C$ in $$C:=\{X\in TM | 1\in I_X\},$$ not points $x$ in $M$.

Comment: In the answer it is considered $X\in T_xM.$ That is the reason to use the notation $\exp_x (X).$

Comment: OK. Could you please supply $X$ and $Y$ into these last two expressions from the displayed formula in your answer: $$...=\gamma(1)=c(k).$$

Comment: I don't know if I have understood your comment. I meant $X\in T_xM$ and $Y=kX\in T_xM.$ Note that when you define $\exp(X)=c_X(1)$ it is $\exp(X)=\exp_x(X_x).$

Comment: I've just meant that the r.h.s. in the last but one line in my OQ has a subscript $X$: $$\exp (tX)=c_X(t).$$ So your last two terms in $$...=\gamma(1)=c(k)$$ should have a subscript $X$ or $Y$ too?

Comment: Since you have used $c_X$ to denote the geodesic you can write $c_X(1).$ And in a similar way we can write $\gamma_Y(k).$ Indeed, we are using that $c_X(t)=c_{tX}(1).$